# SQL query to display the record, If some letters are missing from the record

Tags: ms-access

Eg: Consider ABCDEF are the letters .

ID STATUS  Remarks
1  ABCDEF  {No need to display in result, hence all the letters are present (From ABCDEF Combination)}
2  FEBACD {No need to display in result, hence all the letters are present (From ABCDEF Combination but the sequence is different)}

3 CD {Only letter C and D is present, remaining letters (ABEF are missing, This record needs to be displayed in result)

4) ABE {Only letter AB and E is present, remaining letters (CDF are missing, This record needs to be displayed in result).

**Expected Result:**

ID STATUS

3 CD
4 ABE

Please help me how to achieve this result, I'm basic learner of SQL.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Where Clause I'm using is :

```
WHERE ((InStr([CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS),"D",0) 
Or (InStr([CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS),"E",0) 
Or (InStr([CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS),"L",0));
```

error message:

```
I am getting error as "syntax error (comma) in query expression " in WHERE statement. Could some one clarify whats the error?
```

Comment: WHERE ((InStr([CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS),"D",0) Or (InStr([CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS),"E",0) Or (InStr([CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS),"L",0));

Comment: I am getting error as "syntax error (comma) in query expression " in WHERE statement. Could some one clarify whats the error?

Comment: Add your comments into the question and youve tagged MySQL, Access and SQL Server. Which are you using?

Comment: I am using Access 2016 SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Read in on the `InStr` documentation, a `LIKE` statement will probably help you better.

If you want to use InStr, the following should fix it:

```
  WHERE
  InStr(1, [CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS,"D") = 0
  Or InStr(1, [CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS,"E") = 0
  Or InStr(1, [CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS,"L") = 0;
```

(The first argument of InStr is the search position (may be omitted), with 1 being the first character).

Also, InStr returns either the position of the character or 0 if not found, so you need to compare it either to 0, or to not 0, when testing if something is found.

Alternatively, you can use NOT LIKE, for a more simple syntax.

```
WHERE
  [CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS NOT LIKE "*D*"
  Or [CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS NOT LIKE "*E*"
  Or [CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS NOT LIKE "*F*";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many brackets in your expression, are missing the first argument of `InStr`, and are not performing a comparison (ie. `InStr() > 0`), try this:

```
WHERE
  InStr(1, [CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS,"D") > 0 
  Or InStr(1, [CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS,"E") > 0  
  Or InStr(1, [CMD_PLANT_MATERIAL Query].MAINTENANCE_STATUS,"L") > 0;
```

As a more "SQL" command you might want to go with the answer showing the use of `NOT LIKE`.

Comment: After making above changes, I;m getting below error "ODBC call failed ...[Microsoft][SQL Server]'locate' is not a recognized built-in function name .(#104162)

Comment: Table Name: Missing Values 
{Status alphabets: ABCDEF} 
ID Status
1800 ABCDEF
1811 DEFCBA
1911 ABC
1200 DEF
1400 ADEF
 
Expected Output: 
ID Status
1911 ABC
1200 DEF
1400 ADEF
I am writing SQL queries in access 2016.Please guide me, to display  the record if specific letters are missing from the table record ,If the specific letters are present no need to display the record.

Comment: If you are trying to use SQL Server functions in access it probably won’t work

Comment: "sql server native client11-SSDTBI_VS2012_x86_ENU.e" is connected with access 2016 to access the date base.

Comment: Note that the `NOT LIKE` syntax shared by me should work in SQL Server (you will need to replace `*` with `%` when executing as a passthrough query though), and that @krsmith88 forgot to pass the first argument to `InStr` and forgot to compare the result of `InStr` as outlined by my answer, thus his answer won't work as long as that is not fixed.

Comment: Ok yes, I was answering for Access SQL. @ErikvonAsmuth your answer makes more sense in this case, and is clearer.

Comment: Thank you krsmith88 and erik von asmuth for your help:)

Comment: You should accept @ErikvonAsmuth answer if it helped :-)